# How large a backup can Duplicity handle?

Tags: backup, duplicity

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS for a Samba File Server, and the total Volume of Data is greater than 700GB.

Using the `duplicity` command I first took a full set data backup.  But when I tried to use `duplicity list-current-files`, it was very slow & unable to see all my files. Also, `incr`, `verify` & `collection-status` are very slow and never got the output.

What is the **maximum volume of data** that can be handled by `duplicity`?

Answer (score 0):

Since the commands are executed in the virtual memory it will be the amount of free virtual memory, so the free RAM and the space on the swap partition(s).
The commands do not neccessarily need the full 700 gigabytes to work, but some commands ( but probably not those used by you ) even create a second working copy on a logical space.